# how to find ending position of label with respect to y-axis

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, label

we can find the Left, Right and the Top position of the label by using its properties. how we can find where a label is end with respect to y-axis. as we find top position and how to find down position.

`int  t=label1.Top; //it works how i can find 
int e=label1.End; //or
int d=label1.Down;`

Position of label where it ends. Mean Maximum value of y.

Comment: Label.Bottom is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
int Down= label1.Bottom;
```

or

```
int Down= label1.Top+label1.Height;
```